# JavaFX print a text file

Tags: java, printing, javafx

I made a math programm using JavaFX which calculates some things, and writes all results to a .txt file, but now I want to print that txt out, I found a bit older tutorial using Java's printing dialog, but the document was completely messed up, the other tutorials didn't help, so is there an easy method to just open the Windows Printer Dialog for a text file?

Comment: Did you check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html ?

Comment: @Reek I'm not good in Java, isn't there something easier?

Comment: As soon as you define any specific requirement how the printed page should look, prepare for a headache (regardless of language used). Printing *isn't* a simple topic. Even with a matured printing framework there are hassles to overcome. Asking for something simple is like asking for a miracle.

Comment: By far the easiest thing is to write the text to disk and then use OS tools to print.

Comment: So now, a bit more detailed, i did get it done to print out a Page, using FileInputStream SimpleDoc, it prints it out with PrintService, my txt is coded with ANSI, but my wordwraps show the next line like 20 spaces behind the line before, and I want to set the Printer using printDialog